# What is the ActionMailer configuration for immediate delivery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to know if emails were sent correctly using ActionMailer.deliver_now method. I set the parameter `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors` to true. However nothing was changed. On the other hand, I can find the maillogs which says some mails were bounced or deferred.

The document says `raise_delivery_errors` only works if the external email server is *configured for immediate delivery*.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Here's my question. How can I configure the email server to get the delivery status immediately?

I am now using Rails 4.2.0 and postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64.

Answer (score -1):

I guess action mailer doesn't provide `priority` in its options however what you can do is define priority in the `mail headers` so your delivery agent can `prioritize` it. like we do in `PHP_Mailer`

```
header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
header += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
header += "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n";
header += "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
header += "Importance: High\n";
```

and in your `mail` method

```
mail(to: "abc@example.com", body: "Some Msg", headers: header)
```

But this might not be the problem you are facing.. there might be some problem with your delivery agent or the `actionmailer` configurations.

Comment: As you said, that's not my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: what are your mailer configs... use example data